# Check if nested objects have a specific field set to true

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a domain type `OrderSchema`:

```
public class OrderSchema {
    // properties, etc.
    public boolean isCancellable() {}
    public Foo getFields() {}
}
```

And I have methods `containsNestedOrders(OrderSchema)`, which allows to determine if an `OrderSchema` has nested orders and `hasCancellableOrders(OrderTypeFieldSchema)`, which is meant to find out if the nested orders can be canceled.

```
private boolean containsNestedOrders(OrderSchema orderSchema){ ... }

private boolean hasCancellableOrders(OrderTypeFieldSchema orderSchema){ ... }
```

And there's a method `hasCancellableOrders()` that expects an argument of type `Map<String,OrderSchema>`, inside the method I need to figure if there are any cancellable `OrderSchema` or orders that might be cancel associated with any of `OrderSchema` instances. If any of these conditions meat, method should return `true`.

I am looking for a way to iterate over to iterate over the given `Map` checking these conditions. Below is the logic that I currently have. Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
private boolean hasCancellableOrders(Map<String, OrderSchema> metadata) {
    if (metadata.values().stream().anyMatch(OrderSchema::isCancellable)) {
        return true;
    }
    metadata
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(entry -> containsNestedOrders(entry.getValue()))
        .forEach(entry -> {
            if (
                hasCancellableOrders(((OrderTypeFieldSchema) entry.getValue()).getFields())
            ) {
                boolean b = true;
                return b;
            }
        });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: forEach cant return anything it has void has a return this piece of code can not be compiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach()` operation is not meant to produce a value, its purpose is to perform an action for every stream element. You need `anyMatch()` to check if and `OrderSchema` `isCancellable()` or its nested orders can be canceled.

You can obtain the result in a single iteration over the Values of the given Map (there's no point to iterate twice unless methods `containsNestedOrders()` and `hasCancellableOrders()` are cosful):

```
private boolean hasCancellableOrders(Map<String, OrderSchema> metadata) {

    return metadata.values().stream().anyMatch(orderSchema ->
        orderSchema.isCancellable()
        || containsNestedOrders(orderSchema)
        && hasCancellableOrders(((OrderTypeFieldSchema) orderSchema).getFields())
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you could do different is not `boolean b = true;` and just return the true value with `return true;`

Something like this

```
private boolean hasCancellableOrders(Map<String, OrderSchema> metadata) {
    if (metadata.values().stream().anyMatch(OrderSchema::isCancellable)) {
      return true;
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, OrderSchema> entry : metadata.entrySet()) {
      if (containsNestedOrders(entry.getValue()) && hasCancellableOrders(((OrderTypeFieldSchema) entry.getValue()).getFields())) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```